# Asynchronously load data into object from mysql in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a `User` class.  It's member, `Load` accepts a single parameter which is used to query a user's details from MySQL.  What I'm trying to accomplish is to get the object to populate its own properties from the database, but what's happening is a race condition or something.  Basically, the `Load` function returns true, *then* the value assignments are happening.  Is there a way to write the code so the query completes before the function returns?  I thought something like async/await on the Load function and the db.query() call; but, I don't think the mysql library is written to work like that.

```
const db = require("./db");

class User {
    constructor(loader){
        this.id = loader?.id;
        this.email = loader?.email;
        this.name= loader?.name;
    }

    Load(id=null) {
        let sql = `select usrID, usrEmail, usrName from tblUsers where usrEmail='${id}'`;

        db.connect()

        db.query(sql, (error, results, fields) => {
            if(error) throw error;
            this.id = results[0].usrID;
            this.email = results[0].usrEmail;
            this.name = results[0].usrName;
            }
        });

        db.end()

        return true;
    }
}

// create User and initiate Load

const Robbie = new User();

if(Robbie.Load("rob@example.com")){
    // this is being output before the SQL query finishes, so Robbie.id is always undefined
    console.log("Robbie's ID is", Robbie.id);
}
```

Comment: `Load` performs am asynchronous call to the database, but what you're asking the code to do is to _immediately_ check if the condition has been met even before the value has been returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to accomplish this with *promises.* More on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```html
Load(id = null) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
      // callback if the loading is successful
      resolve();
   }
}


// invoke

Load().then(...);
```